# htaccess conditional rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block public access to a CodeIgniter controller function but this .htaccess rule just won't work:

```
#Block External Access to create pdfs function
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/applicationForm/createPDF
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [F,L]
```

note the x's have been replaced with the servers public IP

I just can't see why this won't work.

The rest of the mod rewrites are working fine:

```
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^x\.x\.x\.x
RewriteRule ^/?applicationForm/createPDF /index.php/$1 [F,L]
```